# using POST request on Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to access graph API to get the number of shares for different pages of my website. I can use the GET method to do so but I want to use POST so that I can send more url in a single request. The current implementation I have for GET is

> http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://umairj.com/,http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 6):

This is badly documented (I mean I didn't find the information when I looked for it!), but there is way to pass all the parameters to the Graph API through POST method:
in your example, you should POST to http://graph.facebook.com/
with the following DATA:
ids=http://umairj.com/,http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/**&method=GET**

I'm not sure about the encoding of the POST DATA..in our case, we were just using ids=.....,.....,..... with numeric FB user ids and we didn't need to do any encoding, but you might need some url-encoding

Don't forget the &method=GET or it won't work ! It helped me break the url length limit that was causing bugs on Internet Explorer (I think RFC says 1024 characters, all browsers support much more, IE only ~4096 ) when we were passing too many ids through GET

if you wish to access non-public information, the same trick works with https://graph.facebook.com/ , provided you add &session_token=*********** to your query

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run a FQL query to get the stats for multiple urls.  [Facebook link_stat documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) has an example of how to do this.  I'm pretty sure you can't POST to either the FQL query or the graph api you were using though unfortunately.  Your FQL query would be:

SELECT url, share_count, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN("http://umairj.com/","http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/")

Here is the url after properly url encoding the query: [https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+url%2C+share_count%2C+like_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+IN%28"http%3A%2F%2Fumairj.com%2F"%2C"http%3A%2F%2Fumairj.com%2F146%2Fhow-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache%2F"%29&format=json](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20url,%20share_count,%20like_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20IN%28%22http://umairj.com/%22,%22http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/%22%29&format=json)

Facebook provides a [FQL testing tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) to help.

---

Update: their [API documention (see section titled "Delete)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) mentions you can do an HTTP POST to any of their methods and set the variable `method` to the method you want. You could try this, although this was designed for delete and put methods not available to javascript clients. It still looks like is all url based so I'm not sure it will take a form encoded parameter like you are looking to do.

Comment: thanks alot :) 
i will try this one, the only thing with post is that I can send multiple urls without having to worry for the query string length restriction

Comment: try the link i added as an update. doubt it will help but worth a try.

Comment: method cannot be used for other methods which arent listed. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I work at Facebook and I've updated our Graph API documentation to document this work around for very large requests:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#largerequests