# Facebook graph api on appengine Invalid Request URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, urllib

I have a request to the fb graph api that goes like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?access_token=<ACCESSTOKEN>&fields=id,name,email,installed&ids=<A LONG LONG LIST OF IDS>
```

If the number of ids goes above 200-ish in the request, the following things happen:

- in browser: works
- in local tests urllib: timeout on deployed
- appengine application: "Invalid request URL (followed by url)"  this
  one doesn't hang at all though

For number of ids below 200 or so , it works fine for all of them.
Sure I could just slice the id list up and fetch them separately, but I would like to know why this is happening and what it means?

Comment: It probably means whatever HTTP library your app uses on appengine can't make GET requests to URLs over a certain length (2K, 4K)?

Comment: makes sense, that was my original guess, but wonder why there isn't a more verbose error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read your question through the first time around.  I didn't scroll the embedded code to the right to realize that you were using a long URL.

There's usually maximum URL lengths.  This will prevent you from having a long HTTP GET request.  The way to get around that is to embed the parameters in the data of a POST request.

It looks like FB's Graph API does support it, according to this question:
[using POST request on Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058302/using-post-request-on-facebook-graph-api)