# Sending facebook graph api batch request as payload in post

Tags: google-apps-script, facebook-graph-api

I want to make a batch request to get data for multiple videos on my facebook page by their id in google app script. However the length of URL should not be more than 2KB.
This is what my GET request looks like in short

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/?batch=[request1,request2,...,request50]
```

Each request looks like this

```
let request_obj = {
    "method": "GET",
    "relative_url": `${video_id}?fields=id,from,created_time,description,length,live_status,title,views,video_insights{name,values}&access_token=${page_access_token}`,
}
```

But sending all this information in the URL of POST request makes the length of URL too long and the request cannot be made.
Is there a way to make a batch request to facebook graph API by sending the batch param in the post request payload instead?

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Is this a standard response from all reputed stackoverflow devs? It's not a question of what's wrong with my code. I believe there is sufficient information in the question. No one needs to look at any code to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

The [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview#largerequests) documentation from facebook is lacking with some alternatives and workarounds.

I notice that  you would need to embed the parameters in the data of the POST request because of the URL length limits when using the GET.

It seems that this particular suggestion was already discussed and documented in another [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058302/using-post-request-on-facebook-graph-api).